# Connecting USB to TTL adapter with sensor node

Tags: uart

I'm currently trying to connect a sensor node's board via a UART.

These are the board's connectors.

[image]

Below is the USB to TTL module I bought. How would I connect these two?

RX, TX and GND make sense but what about SWDIO and SWCLK?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need SWDIO, SWCLK and NRST. These are for SWD debugging / flashing. You only need to connect RX, TX and GND.